# I have to restart IDE to run tests

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-testing

Weird bug with Android Studio 2.2 when running a single test directly in IDE - I'll either have "No tests found" or run my previously compiled test.

Example:

```
@Test
fun testyTest() {
}
```

I'll create this test, and get the "No tests found". So I restart, and test is found! Obviously, the above test passes because it's empty. Next, I want my test to fail. So I manually throw an exception and add one line of code, below.

```
@Test
fun testyTest() {
    throw RuntimeException()
}
```

Now I recompile, and this test passes too, because IntelliJ is for some reason has cached the previous test and reruns that. To get this test to properly fail - I must restart the IDE.

Anyone know what's going on? Note - I'm using Kotlin pretty heavily in this project.

EDIT 2: This is a JVM test (non-android, `src/test/java`) in an android *library* project.

EDIT: here's a full test class

```
package com.example.zak

import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test


class ExampleTest {

    @Before
    fun setUp() {

    }

    @Test
    fun testyTest() {
        //throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add your test class, seeing only bit of code is not enough to say what problem is

Comment: @piotrek1543 it's not relevant. A completely empty test will pass. If add an exception to the test method `throw RuntimeException()` - and recompile then rerun the test, it passes because IntelliJ somehow uses the wrong cache. I have to restart the IDE for the new line of code to be recognized

Comment: Are you running your test in Android Studio on a Windows box?   I have seen the "No Tests Found" error a LOT when running JUnit tests.   Very few google developers use the Windows platform - so there are some unresolved issues due partly to lack of exposure.    Here is a discussion:  http://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing/issues/27

Comment: @JimAndreas on a Mac actually

Comment: Found a bug report on the JetBrains tracker - see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the fix...the issue only occurs when there's a variant selection conflict. Removing the conflict fixed the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check if you're have all these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
  testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Also as you're using `Kotlin` please disable entirely `Instant Run` in `File -> Preferences`.

EDIT: You're talking about tests in library - do `modules` and `project` has these dependencies and proper configuration.

It looks like after Gradle rebuilding, test works fine.

Comment: note - this is actualy a JVM test (non-android) in an android library project.

Answer (score 2):

I found this bug description in the JetBrains IntelliJ bug tracking system.   Here is the URL:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149275

It discusses a change that was made to classloading that may impact Junit test execution.   A workaround is suggested by adding a line to the options.xml config file.  Here is an example workaround for Windows boxes - change as necessary for your platform.   The version of Android below is the current 2.2 release:

1) exit Android studio

2) navigate to the config/options directory for your Android version:

e.g. `C:\Users\YourNameHere\.AndroidStudio2.2\config\options`

3) then add the "`<property name="idea.dynamic.classpath.jar" value="false" />`" line inside the component block of the options.xml file:

```
<component name="PropertiesComponent">
  <property name="idea.dynamic.classpath.jar" value="false" />
```

Start Android Studio and try running local Junit tests.

Comment: I added kotlin and duplicated your lib test pretty much exactly.  It works fine on my system - and if I add the exception, it is properly thrown without needing a restart.   You might try what I normally do when I am stuck, and that is File / Invalidate Caches/Restart (but you probably already tried that!).   So, in summary, your tests work fine on my system, and this suggests something is funny in your test system.   You might just try a fresh install of AS2.2 in a new folder.

Comment: thanks! But I finally figured it out - see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39965565/891242

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use gradle in your project? I had the exact same problem and the solution was to use gradle to execute tests (inside the gradle task list) instead of using the menu (right click on the test file and run tests).

Comment: Yes. Presumably though there's something wrong in our build files that is causing this